# How to use teacup on ubuntu

Tags: scripting, linux, linux-networking

I need to download EXPECT package using teacup on my ubuntu client.

I have installed Active Tcl 8.5. I also have installed EXPECT for LINUX.

But, I don't have EXPECT package to work with Tcl Dev Kit.

Can someone tell me in details on how can I get teacup working in order to download EXPECT package?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

teacup is part of ActiveTcl. In ubuntu 10.04

```
wget http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.5.9.0/ActiveTcl8.5.9.0.293667-linux-ix86-threaded.tar.gz && tar -zxvf ActiveTcl8.5.9.0.293667-linux-ix86-threaded.tar.gz && cd ActiveTcl8.5.9.0.293667-linux-ix86-threaded/ && sudo ./install.sh
$ /opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/teacup version

    8.5.9.0.293667
```

Comment: Hi.I still can't execute teacup.

Comment: administrator@ubuntu:~$ cd /opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin
administrator@ubuntu:/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin$ teacup version
teacup: command not found

Comment: ./teacup or /opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/teacup or export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/